# X value in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Could you pls help me in vhdl/I want to write negative value in my code/I mean like -1 value.

```
--onemore
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity mapper_3 is 
port (  
        clk : in std_logic;
        rst :in std_logic;
        data_in : in std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
        data_out : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end mapper_3;
architecture mapper_3_arch of mapper_3 is 
signal cnt : unsigned(4 downto 0);
constant zeros : std_logic_vector :="00000";
constant zeros_end : std_logic_vector :="000000";
constant ones : signed  := "1";
constant ones_m : signed  := "-1";
constant zero : signed  := "0";
signal out_t : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
signal out_t_1 : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal out_t_2 : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
signal out_t_3 : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);
signal out_t_4 : std_logic_vector(25 downto 0);
signal out_t_5 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin 
-- counter code
process (clk, rst)
begin
if (rst = '1') then
  cnt <= (others => '0');
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
 cnt <= cnt + 1; 
if cnt = 4 then
 out_t <= zeros & conv_std_logic_vector(ones,1);
elsif cnt = 9 then 
 out_t_1 <= out_t & data_in & conv_std_logic_vector( ones_m,1);
elsif cnt = 14 then
 out_t_2 <= out_t_1 & data_in & conv_std_logic_vector(ones,1);
elsif cnt = 15 then
 out_t_3 <= out_t_2 & conv_std_logic_vector(zero,1);
elsif cnt = 21 then
 out_t_4 <= out_t_3 & conv_std_logic_vector(ones_m,1) & data_in &    conv_std_logic_vector(ones,1);
elsif cnt = 26 then
data_out <= out_t_4  & zeros_end;
end if;
end if;
end process;
end mapper_3_arch;
```

when I simulate this code in modelsim,on the position where I trying to write -1,in modelsim its looks like X.Do you have any ideas how to write -1 value.Now data_out looks like 000001data_inXdata_in10X and so on/I want that instead of X,should be -1/is it possible or I dont understand something

Comment: The value "-1" as a string literal representing a signed value gets converted to 'X's because of the meta-value '-' in conv_std_logic_vector where you're specifying a size of 1 (which seems odd, a signed value would be at leat two bits).  See Synopsys std_logic_arith package conv_std_logic_vector[signed, integer return std_logic_vector] and make_binary[signed, integer return std_logic_vector].  It isn't clear from your narrative what you're trying to do and your signal and entity names aren't informative.

Comment: thanks for the answer,so,as I understood I need to change the width of my ones constant on one more

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of this code is quite unclear to me.

You should have a look at how signed numbers are represented in binary. You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

You can have e.g. a sign bit in front (acting like the "-" everone is familiar with in the decimal system) or a 2 complement or any other.